# XML-DTD : Is this correction false?

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm following a course over XML and am doing an exercise on DTD. My answers does not match the site's one.

**EXERCISE**

> - Library must have at least one book
> - Each book has a mandatory attribute : genre.
> - The genre must be one of the followings : fiction, drama, adventure.
> - Each book must have a book and author.

**My Correction**

```
<!DOCTYPE bibliotheque[
    <!ELEMENT bibliotheque (livre)+>

    <!ELEMENT livre (titre, auteur)>
    <!ATTLIST livre (fiction|drame|aventure) #REQUIRED>

    <!ELEMENT titre (#PCDATA) #REQUIRED>
    <!ELEMENT auteur (#PCDATA) #REQUIRED>
]>
```

**The site's correction**

```
<!ELEMENT racine (livre)+ >

<!ELEMENT livre (titre, auteur)+ >
<!ATTLIST livre genre (fiction,drame,aventure) #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT auteur (#PCDATA) >
<!ELEMENT titre (#PCDATA) >
```

The questions are the following :

- I did not consider that a single book could have more than one author so why bother putting a `+` sign on it.
- I considered that the genre must be one of the listed genres so I used a `|` and can not understand the site's decision of using a comma.
- The title and author are logically `required`.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're right and the site is wrong.

```
<!ELEMENT livre (titre, auteur)+ >
```

implies that the sequence titre 'then' auteur is repeatable, which is no sense. By the way, one title and several authors would be written:

```
<!ELEMENT livre (titre, auteur+) >
```

and the enum on an attribute is definitely:

```
<!ATTLIST livre (fiction|drame|aventure) #REQUIRED>
```

commas make no sense here.